# Who is the founder of Hinduism or Sanatana Dharma?

Tags: belief

Who is the founder of Hinduism or Sanatana Dharma like Jesus for Christianity, Prophet Muhammad for Islam  and  Gautama Buddha for Buddhism?

Also which religious book is similar to Bible for Christians and Koran for Muslims?

Comment: Similar to :  http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/732/are-sanatan-dharm-and-hindu-dharm-synonymous-terms-if-not-what-is-the-differen/794#794

Answer (score 3):

**Hinduism was not a religion founded by any one person.**

It was the way of life of the people living in the Indian subcontinent, across the 'Sindh' river. At that time it was known as **"Sanatan Dharma"** or "Eternal Religion".

The teachings of Hinduism were passed down from generation to generation in the form of Vedas.(oral transmission).  **These Vedas contain knowledge and teachings which is in the purest form and directly revealed by the Almighty to enlightened "rishis".**

**Bhagavad Gita (Song of the God)** is the holy book of Hindus. However most of the philosophy in Bhagavad Gita is derived from the **Vedas (Rig Veda, Sama Veda, Yajur Veda and Atharva Veda)** which act as the foundation stone of Hindu beliefs.
To add to it, Bhagavad Gita is a part of the larger epic **"Mahabharata"**

Comment: FYI, 4 vedas, 18 puranas and upanishaths, these are the texts hindus depend. One particular book like Bhagavat Gita can not be counted as the only holy book.

Comment: Re: "It was the way of life of the people living in the Indian subcontinent" - There are claims that Sanatana Dharma was at one time a global spiritual tradition, not bounded by a specific location. In Eurasia in particular, there appear to be statements in the Vedas implying that the Vedic tradition was brought to India from the North by the Aryans, rather than originated in India. This is important because it means that SD is not of Hindu origin, but belongs to all of humanity, even despite the fact that in the recent millennia its practice has been mostly concentrated in India. Comments?