# Did Jesus visit Jagannath Temple of Puri?

Tags: temple, india, christianity

[Levi H. Dowling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_H._Dowling) wrote the book *[The Aquarian Gospel of Jesus the Christ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Aquarian_Gospel_of_Jesus_the_Christ)*.
The title of section VI is: **Life and Works of Jesus in India**, here is an [extract](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Aquarian_Gospel_of_Jesus_the_Christ/Chapter_21):

> "And Jesus was accepted as a pupil in the temple **Jagannath**; and here learned the Vedas and the Manic laws." *section VI, chapter 21, verse 19*

Mark Mason wrote the book *In Search of the Loving God*, here is an [extract](http://www.markmason.net/ch4ex1.htm):

> Sri Daya Mata, president of Self-Realization Fellowship, went to India
>   in 1959, and in an interview with one of India's great spiritual
>   leaders, His Holiness Sri Bharati Krishna Tirtha, the Shankaracharya
>   of Puri, she mentioned that she had been told that Jesus "spent some
>   of his life in India, in association with her illumined sages. His
>   Holiness replied, 'That is true. I have studied ancient records in the
>   Puri Jagannath Temple archives confirming those facts. He was known as
>   "Isha," and during part of his time in India he stayed in the
>   **Jagannath** Temple. When he returned to his part of the world, he
>   expounded the teachings that are known today as Christianity.

Did Jesus really visit Jagannath Temple of Puri?

**Remark**: The two quotes above are not *proofs* of such a visit, but just clues.

Are there *published* "ancient records in the Puri Jagannath Temple archives confirming those facts"?

Comment: I have heard him meeting lord Dattetrayea in Kashmir

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknown_years_of_Jesus these unknown years of jesus are one considered when he met lord Dattatreya the ultimate lord Guru Master who taught Navanathas of nath sampradaya ,so he gave a yog , guru diksha to Jesus as said and he had to meditate for 12 years as other Navnathas.

Comment: @Creator: This complementary information is interesting, unfortunately I don't read anything about lord Dattatreya meeting Jesus on the Wikipedia's page you quote, do you have a reference about this meeting?

Comment: This info is given in Navnath Bhakti Saar or Navnath Charitavalli

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux If Jesus visited Hindu temples, does it make Jesus a Hindu? Does it make him a idol worshiper of Vishnu?

Comment: @Bharat: What's a Hindu?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux, see my answers in [What is the origin of the word “Hindu”?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/65/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-hindu/75#75) & [Is it true that one can not convert to Hinduism from any other religion or vice versa?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/407/is-it-true-that-one-can-not-convert-to-hinduism-from-any-other-religion-or-vice/449#449)

Comment: How is this question related to the study of the Hindu religion? Might be more suited for the Christian site.

Comment: See also the text  [Did Jesus live in India?](http://www.hinduwisdom.info/articles_hinduism/155.htm) about the Natha Namavali.

Comment: this is a duplicate question. This was started by a Russian in the 19th century who had never been to India (according to Swami Vivekananda). btw, it would have been difficult as the Jagannath temple at Puri was built in the 12th century and most of the country was Buddhist at the time of Jesus.....

Comment: I really do not know if Jesus was in India, let alone in the Jagannatha Temple of Puri, but I can tell you something interesting that I heard many years ago from the Hare Krishna devotees (ISKCON). Some devotees theorize that he was probably in India and there was ordained as a Vaishnava devotee, ie as a bhakta devoted to the worship of Lord Vishnu. How so? Some Iskcon devotees noticed at the Shroud of Turin that Jesus has a sign in shape of the letter "U" at the forehead of what looks like a typical Vaishnava sign. ...

Comment: ... Thus the devotees concluded that he probably really was in India, where he became a Vaishnava. Interesting theory, right? :)

Answer (score 11):

**Yeah Jesus did visited Jagannath Temple.** The ancient text in the temple mentioned a foreigner to be a pupil of Hindu Gurus.

What is to be noted here is that, In India his  Hindu masters initiated Jesus into yoga and the highest spiritual life, giving him the spiritual name “Isha” (from 'Ishvar') which is a descriptive title often applied to Gods.

**Zohar (2:188a-b)** a compilation of ancient Jewish mystical traditions and the major text of the Jewish Kabbalah, contains the following incident regarding the knowledge of an illumined rabbi concerning the religion of India and the Vedic religious rite known as the sandhya, which is an offering of prayers at dawn and sunset for enlightenment:

> “Rabbi Yose and Rabbi Hiyya were walking on the road. While they were
>   walking, night fell; they sat down. While they were sitting, morning
>   began to shine; they rose and walked on. Rabbi Hiyya said, ‘See, the
>   face of the East, how it shines! Now all the children of the East [in
>   India], who dwell in the mountains of light [the Himalayas], are
>   bowing down to this light, which shines on behalf of the sun before it
>   comes forth, and they are worshipping it.…Now you might say: ‘This
>   worship is in vain!’ but since ancient, primordial days they have
>   discovered wisdom through it.”

According to Swami Nirmalananda Giri (see [here](http://www.ocoy.org/original-christianity/the-christ-of-india/)):

> “In the nineteen-fifties, the former head of the Govardhan Math, and
>   head of the entire monastic Swami Order of Shankaracharya, Jagadguru
>   Bharat Krishna Tirtha, claimed that he had discovered
>   “incontrovertible historical evidence” that Jesus had lived in the
>   Govardhan Math as well as in other places of India. **He was writing a
>   book on the subject, but died before it could be finished.
>   Unfortunately the fate of his manuscript and research is presently
>   unknown.”**

Moreover, it is generally supposed that at the end of his ministry in Israel Jesus ascended into heaven. But Saint Matthew and Saint John, the two Evangelists that were eye-witnesses of his departure, do not even mention such a thing, for they knew that **he returned to India after departing from them.**

### Now, about some people in Jesus' period.

**Apollonius of Tyna** (born c. 4 AD), the great saint of the Greek world, was a teacher, a great **ascetic**, a **celebate**, a **vegetarian**. **These practices were UNCOMMON among Greeks who practiced Pederast Homosexuality at the time.** **But on the other hand such practices were not only VERY common in India, but were a way of living of Hindus.** A greek sophist of the Roman imperial period, Philostratus has devoted two and a half of the eight books of his *Life of Apollonius* (1.19–3.58) to the description of a **journey of his hero to India.** **So its clear that traveling to India for things like medical treatment, education (Pythagoras traveled to India for treatment of his Epilepsy, thats when he came across the advanced ideas of Geometry taught in Indian 'Gurukuls'. Whatever that has been attributed to him is actually Indian knowledge.)**

**Because of Apollonius' Yogic skills**, Apuleius ranked him with Moses and Zoroaster. Lampridius tells us that Alexander Severus included Apollonius with Abraham, and Orpheus amongst his **household Gods**. For this very fact, he became a hated name among the Christians (here, the followers of Jesus and NOT the Church). In their struggle against Christianity, Pagan philosophers often invoked his name. Hierocles, proconsul of Bithynia under Diocletian (c. 305) cited Apollonius' miracles to show that miracles were not the peculiar property of Christianity. **Orthodox Christians could not believe that there could be such a great ethical and divine character outside the Christian fold, apparently OUT OF JEALOUSY.**

So when it was so common and popular at the time, for the Europeans to travel to India for enlightenment, its not far fetched to believe Jesus must have got his wisdom from Hindu Gurus in India like others at the time. In fact, **the Yogic miracles he showed were COMMON ATTRIBUTES of ascetics in ancient India.** I mean even today there are ascetics in Himalayas who have great Yogic power.

**Jesus was a GREAT ascetic Yogi, trained in India.**

Comment: You wrote "The ancient text in the temple mentioned a foreigner to be a pupil of Hindu Gurus". Did you see these texts by yourself? Else why believe the 
statements of Swami Nirmalananda Giri? Is it possible to consult the archives of the temple? Finally, why this foreigner (Isha) is considered to be Jesus?

Comment: If I say "Yes I have seen those text" then you might reply, "why should I believe your statement". :)
So its better that you seek that for yourself.

"Isha" was name given to Jesus. But Greek language does not have an 'sh' sound. So 'Isha' became 'Isa' for Jesus himself. Wherever he went (apart from Europe) he told himself as 'Isa'. Which is also his currently popular Arabic name, mentioned in Quran. Greeks also had this weird habit of changing the name of everything according to their likings. They change 'Isa' to 'Jesus'. Thus 'Isha' became 'Jesus'.

Comment: If the secret archives of Vatican are made public, you as well as the the western world would know MORE about the Jesus' education in India. Probably Vatican knows everything.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. If you say "Yes I have seen these texts" then I will reply "Could you post a copy here?".

Comment: Apparently this site is more concerned with dogma than history.

Comment: @Hindu You can use normal font.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there published "ancient records in the Puri Jagannath Temple archives confirming those facts"?

Nope. None to speak of. Claims of Jesus in India go back to the 19th century. See the associated [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknown_years_of_Jesus#Claims_of_Jesus_in_India_before_crucifixion). Nicolas Notovich admitted his story was a hoax, and Dowling's source for his own book was "channeling." See Robert Van Voorst's comment (quoted in the article):

> Jesus' putative travels to India and Tibet, his grave in Srinagar, Kashmir, and so forth. Scholarship has almost unanimously agreed that these references to Jesus are so late and tendentious as to contain virtually nothing of value for understanding the Historical Jesus.

Comment: How can you be so sure? And why His Holiness Sri Bharati Krishna Tirtha, the Shankaracharya of Puri would have said : << That is true. I have studied ancient records in the Puri Jagannath Temple archives confirming those facts >>. Do you check these archives by yourself?

Comment: No I haven't checked the temple archives. If the records were "published" I wouldn't need to. ;) That's the question I was answering, at any rate.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to check these archives, and eventually to publish some parts. Perhaps we can ask Swami Nischalananda Saraswati the current Shankaracharya of Puri.

Comment: I have no idea. I'd be in favor of it though, if it were possible.

Comment: Vivekananda, in the late 19th century, also doused a lot of water on the claim pointing out that the Russian had never been to India, and India was mostly Buddhist at the time. Also the temple of Jagganath in Puri wasn't built until the 12th century - 12 centuries after Jesus.

Answer (score 2):

There is no biblical support for the idea that Jesus meditated in India before beginning His ministry in Israel. Nor is there any evidence that He left the land of His birth at any time to go to India or anywhere else. Of the four Gospel accounts, only two mention the birth of Jesus (Matthew and Luke), and only one (Luke) mentions anything about Jesus' life prior to His beginning His three-year ministry in Israel. So, from His birth until 12 years of age, the Bible tells us very little about what happened in Jesus’ life. And from ages 12 to 30, we know nothing. This has led many to speculate as to what Jesus did during those intervening years.

There are many who are convinced that between the ages of 12-29, Jesus travelled . These sorts of claims are presented in the film The Lost Years of Jesus. They are also made in Shirley Maclaine's Out on a Limb, Janet Bock's The Jesus Mystery, Elizabeth Clare Prophet's The Lost Years of Jesus and Holger Kirsten's Jesus Lived in India. Edgar Cayce the trance medium, Bhagwan Shree Rajneesh and Sai Baba have also claimed that Jesus went to India.

**The Life of St Issa**

The claim that Jesus spent his missing years in India originated with Nicholas Notovitch's The Unknown Life of Jesus Christ in 1894. Notovitch, a Russian journalist, claimed he had found documents in a Tibetan Buddhist monastery which described Jesus' life. In these scrolls Jesus was known as St Issa. At the age of 12 he left Jerusalem for India where he studied the Vedas. He was welcomed by the outcasts for his wisdom and miracles but the Brahman priests grew jealous and sent St Issa away. He journeyed to Kashmir and Tibet. In Tibet he mastered the Buddhist Scriptures and then returned to Palestine to preach.

Comment: I'm looking for proofs here. If His Holiness Sri Bharati Krishna Tirtha, the Shankaracharya of Puri said : << *That is true. I have studied ancient records in the Puri Jagannath Temple archives confirming those facts* >>, then it's a clue, and I would like to see a copy of these archives. That's all, it's simple, and then all the debates will be closed.

Comment: I was reading 'the complete works of Swami Vivekananda', in one of his speech about the rishis in India he had mentioned this story by the Russian journalist. But what Vivekanada told is that Jaganath puri was an buddhist temple once. Then it was taken over by Hindus. So if it was a buddhist temple how can Brahmana could be jealous of Jesus and why did he went to Tibet to study buddhist theories if it was a buddihst temple?.So according to him, it is a conspiracy theory against Vedas and Brahmanas.

Answer (score 2):

Jaganatha is actually a Buddhist deity, may be a preceptor of the Buddhist pantheon. According to common perception worshipers were regarded as Brahmin priests. But about the evidence as claimed to have seen by Bharati Krushna Tirtha cannot be ignored because we do not have access into the corresponding temple record. It is a fact that then during the life time of Jesus Puri was an important seat of knowledge and spiritualism. And the place had foreign connection both in the east and middle east from 261 BC and then Puri was a famous trade center too which has been testified from discovery of Kushan coins. Thus historically visit of Jesus cannot be regarded as mere hypothesis. Yet scholars are attempting to collect striking evidences.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda has said in his writings that these stories about Jesus visiting India can all be traced to a 19th century Russian. At the time of Jesus most of India was Buddhist.

Comment: Now further researches have shown its truth.