# What was the meaning of "Achar Samhita" 2000 years ago?

Tags: scripture

In this video is talked about that Jesus Christ studied the  "Achar Samhita" 2000 years ago somewhere in India. When I'm looking on the internet they talk about political elections. 
So I am not sure what the Achar Samhita meant 2000 years ago? Is this still a used book, what is written in it, and is it a Buddhism book or Hinduism book?

min 49:28
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfEkM2tl_lg

Comment: So what you see on youtube and the internet should be taken as truth without proper evidence based citations and proper research? Why don't you ask the person who did the video what their sources are? Usually upon one or two pertinent questions their 'evidence' fades quickly

Comment: You are wright concerning the truth about it, but my question is just where that document is about.

Comment: @Marijin You can found some related information in replies on [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/did-jesus-visit-jagannath-temple-of-puri) and [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-jesus-an-avatar-of-lord-vishnu) question. Please note that these are not answers to your question but could be some info related to the subject.

Comment: Some people I know believe that Jesus came to India and became enlightened before going back. Although, it is a fact the there is a specific period in his younger ages, during which his whereabouts are unknown.