# Is Jesus really one of the disputes of Sidhas in Himalayas?

Tags: vedas, puranas, belief, christianity

I came to know that Jesus in his childhood, in spite of giving respect to his father Joseph's words, came to India to learn magical talents and spirituality from Sidhas in Himalayas. After learning the arts from them, he went back to his land and implementing these talents and thus impressed many followers in the western side and now he gets many followers all around the world.
(These are some of the information from materials)

He always mentioned about God in Heaven as his father and that God, he mentioned should be Lord Shiva since he is the head of the all Sidhas.

Is that true?

Comment: Related [Did Jesus visit Jagannath Temple of Puri?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2246/3500)

Comment: [There is no credible, sound evidence that Jesus visited India.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/18141/3961)

Comment: "Jesus in India" is a treatise written by Mirza Ghulam Ahmad, the founder of the Ahmadiyya Movement.The treatise suggests that Jesus, starting his journey from Jerusalem and passing through Nasibus and Persia, eventually reached Afghanistan where he met the Israelites who had settled there after their escape from the bonds of Nebuchadnezzar. From here he travelled to Kashmir where some Israelite tribes had also settled. Here he lived until his death at an old age.

Comment: This was first started by a Russian in the 19th century who never visited India. Swami Vivekananda dismissed the claims more than 100 years ago. There is no historical evidence that any Israelis ever went to Afghanistan or Kashmir. Proof lies in the assertion, not in the negation. What 'proofs' does the treatise offer for its claims?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that people who ask this and similar questions to this one make one terrible mistake, so to speak, namely they ask questions such as "Did Jesus visit India". Instead of asking questions was Jesus in India it would be much more relevant and much more interesting to ask a question as to how much teachings of *historical* Jesus (here I put the emphasis on the "historical", an explanation follows below) have a similarity with holy teachings of India, and from that standpoint to examine how much of his teachings may have been inspired or influenced with those of ancient India. And then from this it could possibly follow that Jesus somewhere may have learned some holy teaching of ancient India, whether himself traveled to India or by some other means.

During the past century there were some books written about similarity of his teachings with those of Buddhism, and similar book could be written about similarity with Hinduism.
Here is one nice book on the subject, it's *Jesus and Buddha: The Parallel Sayings* by Marcus J. Borg in which he says at page 4 (see at Google books):

> The correlations among these ancient texts are almost `eerie`. As will
>   become immediately evident in the collections of parallel sayings that
>   follow, Jesus' and Buddha’s later teachings are as alike as their
>   early biographies. Whether speaking of love, material wealth,
>   temptation or salvation, they were two masters with one message.

Having examined the parallel sayings of Jesus and Buddha's teachings, professor Borg finds them to be almost `eerie`! And since it is a well known fact that the Buddha has taken many elements of his teachings from the Hindu holy scriptures, how would it, then, that be eerily similar to compare historical Jesus' and Hindu teachings?

Now follows a brief explanation of the term "historical" to which I highlight above. The scientists studying Jesus as a historical person come to the conclusion that his teaching was very different from what the Christian idea of his teachings were. A simple google search on *Borg historical Jesus* will do.
To say it another way: To compare historical Jesus' and Hindu teachings does not necessarily mean something like to compare Christian and Hindu teachings!

I think that what I said above is much more relevant and gives much more weight to search for possible evidence that Jesus was familiar with the teachings of ancient India, Buddhism and Hinduism, and then that he used these teachings as a kind of inspiration for what he taught -- this is much more relevant than, let's say, some stories about Jesus from Kashmir or something like, see linked question above right, *Did Jesus visit Jagannath Temple of Puri?*

- see also about prof. Marcus J. Borg at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Borg

**Update:**

Scientists do not think that Jesus was a Christian!
It is that Christians think he was a Christian, but scientists do not think so. Scientists believe that Jesus preached one faith completely unknown to us, and that was not Christianity, and later some people have turned that faith into what is now known as Christianity.
Scientists are trying to figure out exactly what kind of faith was that what Jesus had preached. It is in the context of research of Jesus as a historical figure, as I mentioned in the answer here it's "historical Jesus". See about historical Jesus scholarship at the wiki link on Marcus J. Borg that I posted above.

In response to the question I have considered the possibility of influence of Hinduism and Buddhism to Jesus and his teachings.
One of the leading scientists in the study of the historical Jesus, Marcus J. Borg, discussed the similarities between historical Jesus' and Buddha's teachings. I think that from that it can be seen the potential impact of the buddhist and the hindu teachings on the Jesus' teachings.

Comment: “ It is that Christians think he was a Christian, but scientists do not think so. Scientists believe that Jesus preached one faith completely unknown to us, and that was not Christianity, and later some people have turned that faith into what is now known as Christianity.” <—— Yep. 100%  I spent huge parts of my life in Christian churches and schools (long story ) What was taught is not what modern people in this religion think it is.