# Young Jesus' India visit

Tags: history, other-religions, india, christianity

Did Jesus Christ visit India when he was aged between 13 and 30? Is there any ancient record about his connection to life, culture or religion of India?

Comment: Also, see [Is Jesus really one of the disputes of Sidhas in Himalayas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10363/2995)