# Who first coined the term Sanatan Dharma?

Tags: scripture, vedas, bhagavad-gita, dharma, upanishads

When did we get the name "Sanatan Dharma"? Is "Sanathan Dharma" and Hinduism one and the same? I see hardly people know about Sanatan Dharma. Mostly in North India, people know it and in the South, people are somewhat ignorant about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Origin of the Sanatan Dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/origin-of-the-sanatan-dharma)

Comment: No one coined the term Sanatana Dharma.Sanatana meaning eternal as our culture is eternal without any beginning or end it's called Sanatana.Now, though Dharma in english is translated as religion but actually the most close translation for me would be the rightful duty one should follow (Dhārañ).As 4 hindu,it ws givn 2 us by persian attackers as we live near Sindu (Indus) river and calld our country hindustan. Britz just puts ism behind it.Same wt name India which brits gave cz of Indus river.Our country's real name is Bharat n Sanatan Dharma is a scientific n cultural way of living life.Prd..

Answer (score 4):

That phrase came from Sage Valmiki himself. In Valmiki Ramayana, it occurs several times. Here is one instance -

[Bala Kanda, 25th Sarga](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga25/bala_25_frame.htm) -

*Nrusamsam Anrusamsam va prajA rakshaNa kAranAth,
pAthakam va sa dosham va kartavyam rakshatA sadA,
rAjyabhAra niyuktAnAm ee-eshA **dharma sanAthana** ha....*

*Meaning:* For the reason of protecting people, a protector always has to execute such deed, whether it is ruthless/cruel or humane, sinful or vilifying. To the nominee who bears the burden of ruling a kingdom this is the ***eternal path of righteous conduct***..

*Sanatana dharma* is the same as *Dharma sanatanaha*. The former is used when emphasizing *dharma* as a priority, and the latter is used when emphasizing the *eternality* aspect of it as a priority.

[image]

The word 'Hinduism' didn't exist until recently. Because as you know 'Hindu' itself is a Persian word for 'Sindhu'. But yes, Hinduism is the current avataar of Sanatana Dharma. And I know many South Indians who know this correct term for our religion.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Varnashrama dharma / sanadhana dharma (the following is from Gandhiji's speech delivered on 16/09-1927 at Thanjavur)   "in my opinion there is no such thing as inherited or acquired superiority." I believe in the rock-bottom doctrine of advaita and my interpretation of advaita excludes totally any idea of superiority at any stage, whatsoever.

Comment: Except your quote doesn't contain the phrase in it, so how does this answer the question?