# Is everyone a Hindu?

Tags: other-religions

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism):

> Hinduism includes a diversity of ideas on spirituality and traditions, but has no ecclesiastical order, no unquestionable religious authorities, no governing body, no prophet(s) nor any binding holy book; Hindus can choose to be **polytheistic, pantheistic, monotheistic, monistic, agnostic, atheistic or humanist**

Different Hindus worship God in their own different ways.

Does that mean everyone is a Hindu?

Comment: Related [What is the origin of the word “Hindu”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/65/3500)

Comment: If the term Hindus is only applied to Sanatana Dharma people as mentioned in 
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/75/489 this 
 answer, then only believers in Vedas are hindus, but nowadays this definition is often corrupted and many nastika (those who do not believe in authority of vedas) schools are included in Hinduism. So it totally depends on your perception of the word 'Hindu'.

Comment: All hindus (followers of Vedanta) believe in God, all hindus accept the vedas as the revealed word of God, and all hindus believe in cycles and reincarnation. If you can't check of these three you're not a Hindu. There is no polytheism in Hinduism. There have been agnostics and atheists in Indian culture, but they are not Hindus (vedantists).

Comment: What `other-religions` tag is doing here?

Comment: I didn't know what tag to use

Comment: Atheistic, agnostic, humanist are not "Hindu" philosophies. Hindu by defition is one who believes in and accepts the authority of the Veda.

Answer (score 3):

You can call someone Hindu if -

- He/She believes in Karma theory.
- He/She derives his philosophy from Vedas or Āgamas (revelations). See, it is not necessary whether he/she have read scriptures or not, it's just that his/her philosophy should derive from these scriptures.
- He/She never partakes flesh of cow as cow is substrata of Vedic/Yajna culture (of course milk giving mother as well). Yajnas are impossible to carried out without cows. Prerequisites materials used in Yajna can't be derived in absence of cows.

Answer (score 1):

**No Every one is not Hindu.**

Because of Every religions have different regions and different time lines.

For more detail you can look this image

[image]

Comment: The picture is not factually correct. That is from western perspective. Btw, please mention source of that picture?

Comment: Source of above Image : http://sploid.gizmodo.com/the-history-of-all-religions-explained-in-one-fascinati-1643222359