# Is it Sanatan Dharma OR Sanatan Dharam?

Tags: dharma

Can someone please clarify what is the right spelling and pronounciation in Sanskrit - Sanatan **Dharma** OR Sanatan **Dharam**??

I always thought 'Dharma' was an English term and 'Dharm' Hindi/ Sanskrit. Like Rama English for Ram and Mahabharata for Mahabharat.

Comment: It is Dharma ( धर्म ), not Dharam ( धरम ).. maybe you can say Dharm ( धर्म् )

Comment: _So, it is pronounced as 'Dharma' in Sankrit not Dharm?_ - Righto. Both Hindi & Sanskrit use Devanagiri script but due [schwa deletion rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa_deletion_in_Indo-Aryan_languages) in Hindi, Dharma is pronounced Dharm in Hindi.

Answer (score 3):

Both spellings are wrong as per [Sanskrit to English transliteration schemes](https://web.archive.org/web/20161019031628id_/http://www.sanskrit-sanscrito.com.ar/en/learning-sanskrit-transliterating-2-1/411#Comparexamples).

According to [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration) scheme, सनातन धर्म is written **sanātana dharma** or if you wish to capitalize the first letters, **Sanātana Dharma** also works.

[Harvard-Kyoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard-Kyoto) (HK) is much simpler and easy to type. In HK, it would be **sanAtana dharma**.

When in doubt, you can use [spokensanskrit.org](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=sanAtana&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) and search for a word using its approximate English spelling. It then shows the correct spelling in both Devanāgarī and English (IAST or HK).

For the correct pronunciation of *sanātana dharma*, check the beginning of [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZ9pCM-FAMA) (*Sanatana Dharma An Introduction_Part-1/9_What is Sanatana?*).

Also, see:

- [Why we put 'A' after each Hindu name?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15617)
- [When was the expression "Sanatana Dharma" first used and what does it mean?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24380)

Comment: Harvard Kyoto is bit difficult because sh in Shiva is written as Z and the name becomes ziva. It is easy in IAST because  it allows capital letters whereas ITRANS or HK doesn't. The pronunciation changes.

Comment: But HK is easy to type. Problem with ITRANS is it has versions and no way to tell which version you're using. Two people conversant with both HK & IAST may prefer to use HK for a quick informal chat. @Sarvabhouma