# Is it sin for Brahmins if they eat artifical meat (Cultured meat)?

Tags: scripture, sin, non-vegetarian

Is it sin for Brahmins if they eat artifical meat ([Cultured meat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultured_meat) )? Does scriptures scriptures say anything about this?

Comment: they're not supposed to eat even onion and garlic, what to ask of lab meat ?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to HSE!! I'd suggest you to please visit this [FAQ INDEX on the HSE META](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) , please go through it properly and then you may get started in here for an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: And In case, you feel your doubt is answered fully and you are satisfied with the answer given, @Karna . S, you may click on this - - > [✅] button, below the voting buttons  and accept the answer as this turns green --> [✔️] . You may also contribute an upvote (), if you liked the answer.

Comment: Haha, Thanks @Archit. I guess, maybe, I too will get bored eventually. ;))

Comment: @Vivikta I got 11 points, I can't upvote your answer. Looks like you got confused by voting thing in SE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a brahmin eat meat according to shastras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33572/can-a-brahmin-eat-meat-according-to-shastras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, this does "seem" to be like a newly discovererd [loophole](https://www.livekindly.co/lab-meat-vegan/#:%7E:text=Lab%2Dgrown%20meat%20is%20meat,is%20free%20from%20animal%20use.). Since, the *hiṃsā* (violence) part, explicitly seems to be missing, which in the otherwise natural case involves - killing the animal itself. And in that way, one may argue that yes, since no kind of violence is involved and no *jīvātman* seems to be harmed, thus, we are allowed to eat the "Cultured Meat". However, a meat is a meat, even if lab grown. Anything derived, for the purpose of eating and based on a living creature is called as [meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat).

As discussed appropriately in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/why-are-hindus-vegetarian-what-is-the-real-meaning-of-the-word-mamsah-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%83), *hiṃsā* is to be avoided:

> > According to Bhishma there are four ways to follow Ahimsa Dharma. By
> > Mana (mind), by Speech , by Karma and not eating flesh . So all these
> > are part of Ahimsa Dharma and not eating flesh is one of them.
>
> > चतुर्विधेयं निर्द्रिष्टा ह्यहिन्सा ब्रह्मवादिभि : | एकैकतोSपि
> > विभ्रष्टा न भवत्यरिसूदन ||4||
>
> > "Bhishma said, 'Utterers of Brahma have said that there are four kinds
> > of compassion or abstention from injury.
>
> > i.e. even by mentally mentally committing an act of slaughter, one
> > becomes guilty of it. So those who are wise avoid it because to follow
> > Ahimsa Dharma.

Further, it's very important to know, that the restrictions are not just de-limited to violence based foods, but, what to eat and what not to eat, is largely prescribed and defined by the three *guṇas* - *sāttvika*, *rājasika*, *tāmasika* modes of the material nature.
You may refer, to [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/what-are-tamasic-rajasic-and-sattvic-foods), for the three categories of food attributes.

Any kind of meat (derived by whatsoever methodology), will unequivocally and definitely fall under the [*tamasic* category](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/what-are-tamasic-rajasic-and-sattvic-foods), and as such is to be restricted for *Brahmins* and in general, also forbidden/[not recommended](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29703/what-food-is-suggested-for-yogi) for anyone on a [spiritual path](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40781/does-consuming-non-vegetarian-food-hinder-our-spiritual-progress).

Further, the argument deriving its basis on the fact that -

> " cultured meat is not *hiṃsā* (even though it's a living mass of
> cells derived from the live body of an animal, but grown in a lab).
> This is similar to just like one may consider plants are living and
> thus why do we eat that? "

You may refer to this excellent QnA to resolve that doubt - [Why can we eat 'living' plants but not 'living' animals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/97/why-can-we-eat-living-plants-but-not-living-animals/112#112).

And thus, to conclude for the question posed - **No**, a *Brahmnin* is recommended to not eat **any kind** of meat.