# What's the Sri Vaishnava stand on non vegetarianism?

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, tradition, non-vegetarian

What is the stand of Sri Vaishnava parampara/sampradaya on non vegetarianism? Would like to know from a traditional and scriptural perspective, from a traditional Sri Vaishnava.

Comment: Definitely not allowed. Lookup "Ahara Niyamam". Also the meaning of word meat [mamsah](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/why-are-hindus-vegetarian-what-is-the-real-meaning-of-the-word-mamsah-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%82%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%83), and why it is a spiritual handcuff