# Regarding meat eating

Tags: shiva, food, vedic-rituals, non-vegetarian, kali

Is there any process or procedure available in Hinduism before eating meat like halal in Islam or some other process in Christianity? Any prayer or deity to be remembered before eating meat? Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Hindus vegetarian? What is the real meaning of the word 'mamsah' (मांसः) or meat?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/why-are-hindus-vegetarian-what-is-the-real-meaning-of-the-word-mamsah-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%82%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%83)

Comment: Eating meat is strictly prohibited in Hinduism, and why will there be something to be performed before meat eating if meat eating is not allowed in the first case?

Comment: There is no prohibition in the vedas as to meat eating. This is a latter day development. If you are leading the life of a recluse, then no need for meat. Religion is in realization, not in the kitchen. Strive for God realization, meat eating will renounce you at the proper time. Many people repeat Gita 4.24 before taking meals.